# bootstrapping resampling for unfair dice

Tags: bootstrap, resampling, dice

Let's say I've been given an unfair dice. After 1000 throws, these are the empirical frequencies:

- 1, 100
- 2, 100
- 3, 100
- 4, 100
- 5, 100
- 6, 500

I would like to represent this in a barplot, where each bar is simply the empirical probability. Does it make sense to use bootstrapping + resampling to add confidence bars ?

If the barplot showed derived measures, such as the mean, then I would see why confidence bars would be important. Each such measure would hide the underlying distribution. And by adding confidence bars, I can give some intuition on how sensitive the measure is.

But my barplot would only contain the raw empirical probabilities. What information could be added by confidence bars?

Comment: While the results you have are counts (which are fixed) you can also look at them as being the sample proportions (a statistical quantity) times the $n$. So a bootstrap interval makes sense.

Comment: but what is the additional information here? If I have a derived measure, I see how the confidence intervals can expose sensibility with respect to the underlying distribution. But here, I don't get it.
Let's say it's an unfair coin. One side came up 900 times, the other 100 times. Why should I resample this ? The resampling is in itself based on the empirical result.

Comment: In this instance theory provides analytical expressions for excellent confidence intervals: no bootstrapping is needed.  (All of them would be close to what a Normal approximation gives with very little calculation: you could do it in your head.)  These CIs would have noticeable lengths, because *this is a sample:* in another experiment of the same size the results very likely would be different, so it's useful to provide an indication of how much a difference could be expected.